# Why pip3 is not working with root in Tails4.22 OS using proxychains

Tags: python, linux, pip, tor, torsocks

I am using Tails4.22. I want to run this command which is
sudo pip3 proxychains install selenium
The problem is this command runs successfully without sudo and I want to use it with root.
Conf file in /etc/proxychains.conf has all these lines in it.

```
# proxychains.conf  VER 3.1
#
#        HTTP, SOCKS4, SOCKS5 tunneling proxifier with DNS.
#

# The option below identifies how the ProxyList is treated.
# only one option should be uncommented at time,
# otherwise the last appearing option will be accepted
#
dynamic_chain
#
# Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#strict_chain
#
# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#random_chain
#
# Random - Each connection will be done via random proxy
# (or proxy chain, see  chain_len) from the list.
# this option is good to test your IDS :)

# Make sense only if random_chain
#chain_len = 2

# Quiet mode (no output from library)
#quiet_mode

# Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
proxy_dns

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

# ProxyList format
#       type  host  port [user pass]
#       (values separated by 'tab' or 'blank')
#
#
#        Examples:
#
#             socks5 192.168.67.78 1080 lamer secret
# http 192.168.89.3 8080 justu hidden
# socks4 192.168.1.49 1080
#        http 192.168.39.93 8080
#
#
#       proxy types: http, socks4, socks5
#        ( auth types supported: "basic"-http  "user/pass"-socks )
#
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks5 127.0.0.1 9050
```

When I run the commmand without root it runs succesfully but with sudo this is the output that I get.

```
pypi.org does not exist
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x705278b75860>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 1] Unknown error')': /simple/selenium/
|DNS-request| pypi.org
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
```

I have also tried with torsocks and having the same issues. Thanks in advance.